# Terraform local map spread across files and merge

Tags: terraform, hashicorp

I have a locals defined like below

```
locals {
  mymap = {
    abc = {

    }
    pqr = {

    }
    xyz = {

    }
  }
}
```

I refer these using locals.mymap[$var] where $var can be "abc", "pqr" or "xyz"

Now content of abc, pqr and xyz has grown big over time and I want to separate these into 3 different .tf files. How do I achieve this? Ideally I need something like below but still able to refer these using locals.mymap[$var] where $var can be "abc", "pqr" or "xyz"

abc.tf

```
locals {
  mymap = {
    abc = {

    }
  }
}
```

pqr.tf

```
locals {
  mymap = {
    pqr = {

    }
  }
}
```

xyz.tf

```
locals {
  mymap = {
    xyz = {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds as if these should be external data and not locals.

Comment: splitting one terraform file into several but running the normal terraform apply will not work. as terraform will just collect up all the resources together then build the graph. So in this case assuming these files are all in the same dir you will get an error `A local value named "mymap" was already defined`